# Add information like store address in order email

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Woocommerce website and I need to add the store address into the email template of the order.
I would like to add the "Method Description" that include our store address into the email of the order. Is it possible?
The value of "Method Description" is: value="flexible_shipping_single:12"

How can I operate in this way? Which email template I have to edit?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand your question. But I think this is what you need. If you need to add a new row to the order table to show method description, then you don't have to edit any WooCommerce email templates to achieve this. You can make use of the filter `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals`. Following is an example

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'add_method_description', 10, 2 );
function add_method_description( $total_rows, $order ) {
    $total_rows['method_description'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Your Label', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'   => 'value here'
    );
    return $total_rows;
}
```

You can write code to get the value and pass it here.